# Double bracket Cast

Tags: c#, interface, casting

Normal cast is achieved with something like this

```
(int)foo;
```

however I came across a piece of code where I found:

```
((IFoo)object).Method();
```

I don't understand what is happening here, although in intelli sense I can see exposed method on the interface. Which I cannot get if I did `(IFoo)foo;`

Thanks

Comment: If you wouldn't use the extra brackets, you would try to call `FooMethod()` on `foo`, not on the casted `foo`.

Comment: Why name it `foo` if it is not an `IFoo` (or a class that implements `IFoo`), and if it does then you should not need to cast. (If you want an `IFoo` but had an `Object`, then `var foo = obj as IFoo;`)

Comment: you are right, it is object. @crashmstr it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is about operator precedence. In

```
(IFoo)foo.Bar();
```

the member access operator `.` has precedence, so it's evaluated first. `foo.Bar()` is called and the result is cast to `IFoo`.

In

```
((IFoo)foo).Bar();
```

the parentheses establish a different precedence. `foo` is cast to `IFoo` first, and the `IFoo` then has `Bar()` called on it.

This can be a pretty common technique, so good question. You'll be seeing more like this as time goes on. :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I understand it now :)

Answer (score 1):

In the example given...

```
((IFoo)foo).FooMethod();"
```

...the foo object is being cast to an IFoo interface. THEN, the FooMethod() of the IFoo interface is being called. The brackets ensure that the cast takes place FIRST, to ensure that the method is called on the object AFTER it has been cast to the appropriate interface. As Greg rightly stated, it is simply about operator precedence.

Comment: Thanks for your input :)